# Integrating a function with two arguments in R

Tags: r, integrate

I have the following Taper function:

```
taper <- function(midd,midh){
    midh <- midh+0.2
    tFactorSBD <-      1.3/midh
    qFactorSBD <-      (0/100)/midh
    YFactorSBD <-      (1-qFactorSBD^0.5)/(1-tFactorSBD^0.5)
    aux1SBD <-         0.6624965*(YFactorSBD^0.1)+ 0.3781478*(qFactorSBD^4)
    aux2SBD <-         -0.4418430*asin(1-sqrt(qFactorSBD))
    aux3SBD <-         -0.5154988/exp(midd/midh)
    aux4SBD <-         0.0197963*midd^YFactorSBD
    ExpFactorSBD <-    aux1SBD+ aux2SBD+ aux3SBD+ aux4SBD
    diam <- 0.8795844*(midd^0.9457765)*(midh^0.1061692)*(YFactorSBD^ExpFactorSBD)
    area<- pi*((diam/2)^2)/10000 
    return(area)
}
```

I want to integrate that to calculate the volume, going from 0.2 to midh(in my example I'm testing 15.1). I've tried this:

```
volume <- integrate(taper, 0.2, 15.1, midd=13.5)
```

but this message appeared:

```
Error in integrate(taper, 0.2, 15.1, midd = 13.5) : 
  non-finite function value
```

Any hints on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
unlist(lapply(seq(0.2, 2.4, 0.1), function(x) taper(15.1, x)))
```

Gives

```
 [1]           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           Inf           Inf           Inf
[13]           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf           Inf 9.064414e+221
```

So `taper` is returning either `NaN` or `Inf` for values of `midh` below about 2.3.  That why you can't integrate: the integral is undefined.  You need to work out what `taper` should be returning.

Also, note that `integrate` supplies the *first* argument to its argument `f`, which is `taper` in your case.  You need to supply the others.  But the first argument to `taper` is `midd`.  So that's getting passed twice (once by `integrate` and once by you). `midh` is never defined.

The first line of your function, `midh <- midh+0.2` looks odd.

And `qFactorSBD <- (0/100)/midh` means `qFactorSBD` is `0` by definition.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I replied to your comment with a new answer!

Comment: Will you post a sample of your input data, please?  (The output from `dput()` run on your data frame would be udeal.  Or, if that's too big, `dput(head())`.)  Would you explain what your `taper` function is trying to do, please?  Also, there's no 'simulation' involved when you use `integrate`.  Google "trapezium rule" if you want an example of numerical integration.  `integrate` doesn't use the trapezium rule, but the same principles apply.

Comment: > dput(head(StandData))
structure(list(Stand = c("s3 .", "s3 .", "s3 .", "s3 .", "s3 .", 
"s3 ."), Age = c(44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49), SAge = c(44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49), Sumvol = c(272, 275.6, 279.2, 282.8, 286.4, 290), 
    Midd = c(13.5, 13.88, 14.26, 14.64, 15.02, 15.4), Midh = c(15.3, 
    15.58, 15.86, 16.14, 16.42, 16.7)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: the taper function calculates the diameter of a tree at a given height. With this diameter, I calculate the area correspondent to that diameter. The integrate function is supposed to calculate the volume of the whole tree, going from 0.2 cm to the total height. I will google that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. Yes, you were right. The taper function had some problems.
I think it works now:

```
taper <- function(x,midh,midd){
  tFactorSBD <-      1.3/midh
  qFactorSBD <-      x/midh
  YFactorSBD <-      (1-qFactorSBD^0.5)/(1-tFactorSBD^0.5)
  aux1SBD <-         0.6624965*(YFactorSBD^0.1)+ 0.3781478*(qFactorSBD^4)
  aux2SBD <-         -0.4418430*asin(1-sqrt(qFactorSBD))
  aux3SBD <-         -0.5154988/exp(midd/midh)
  aux4SBD <-         0.0197963*midd^YFactorSBD
  ExpFactorSBD <-    aux1SBD+ aux2SBD+ aux3SBD+ aux4SBD
  diam <- 0.8795844*(midd^0.9457765)*(midh^0.1061692)*(YFactorSBD^ExpFactorSBD)
  area<- pi*((diam/2)^2)/10000
  return(area)
}

vol <- integrate(taper, 0.2, 15.1, midh=15.1, midd=13.5)$value
print(vol)
```

I am not familiar with Integrals at all, but I think the "x" would be the values to be simulated, ranging from 0.2 to midh.

The problem is that I have a dataframe with hundreds of combinations of midh and midd, and I must calculate "vol" for all of them.

The part I am struggling now is how to insert the integrate function in a loop that will give me all values of vol for each combination of midh and midd.

Any hints?

Thanks for taking the time to help a beginner in R =)